# How to change the text of a radio button based on the selection in the spinner which are both within a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a spinner which holds the years as ranges.
**fromYear**-**toYear**
For example:

- 2015-2016
  2016-2017

I need to check if the **toYear** is a leap year on selection and based on if it is leap year or not i need to change the text of radio buttons in a group placed below the spinner.

There are 3 radio buttons within the group.

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to refine your question with additional information, such as code and error message to describe your programming problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must get selected item `String` from your `Spinner` , to do that you must check `setOnItemSelectedListener` method and when user choosed one item from your spinner you get the selected item `String` value try this code to get it :

```
String Text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Then you must check `text` value to get **ToYear** from it .

In Java you can user `substring()` method.

For example if selected item `text` equals **2015-2016** :

```
text.substring(5,4);
```

This will return you **2016** and you can do something you like by checking it ,

You can change start and end index if it is't returned true value . this is the standard type of `substring` usage :

```
str.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
```

Comment: i got it.Thank you for the answer :)